# JSON format with paranthesis

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm returning a map of list from  the apex class, the JSON in JS controller has a parenthesis around the key

```
[Account (Id:a6Lq00000004UdJEAU, Name:Account1)]":[]
```

is this format valid? how do I get the Id from the above account?

In my aura iteration {!obj.Account.Id} seems to be invalid.

UPDATE:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<Account,List<contact>> getRelatedcontacts()
{
    //userAccounts is a SOQL         
    for(Account acc : userAccounts)
    {
        List<contact> contactList = new List<contact>();
        if(accountContactMap.get(acc.primaryId__c) != null)
        {
            contactList = accountContactMap.get(acc.primaryId__c);
        }
        contactList.addAll(acc.Contacts); // list of contact
        accountContactMap.put(acc.primaryId__c, contactList);
    }
}
```

I cannot add the whole class,but it looks something similar to what I've added,

Comment: No, that's not valid JSON. How did you generate this string? Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: @sfdcfox I've added some relevant code

Comment: Ideally, you could just return the results from the query, otherwise you could write a wrapper class for this. Your key needs to be a primitive (e.g. an ID) if you want to return a usable map. In your case, though, I think a list of items would be easier to work with.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but I just wanted to know why the map would return a wrong JSON.

Comment: JSON doesn't support objects as keys, so Salesforce does the only sensible thing it can; it converts the object to a string via toString. This is why you need to use a primitive, such as an Id or something.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it was created via:

```
theAccount.toString();
```

instead of using

```
JSON.serialize(theAccount);
```

Comment: I've updated my question, it is returning the complete SOQL in paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getRelatedcontacts()
{
    //userAccounts is a SOQL         
    for(Account acc : userAccounts)
    {
        List<contact> contactList = new List<contact>();
        if(accountContactMap.get(acc.primaryId__c) != null)
        {
            contactList = accountContactMap.get(acc.primaryId__c);
        }
        contactList.addAll(acc.Contacts); // list of contact
        accountContactMap.put(acc.primaryId__c, contactList);
    }

    return JSON.serialize(accountContactMap);
}
```